Trying to connected logitech g27 with an ESP32-S3
i am trying to connect my logitech to g27 and configure it and read values from it but im have trouble doing so ,
i setup my esp32-s3 using platformIO espidf and the board be esp32OTG , tried the example code and still not connected ,
the most success i got is using the ESP32_HOST_HID library by esp32beans on github which managed to start my logitech and read value from it but it did not recognize nor managed to configure it , is there a way i can do it easily ? i searched and no one did it as far as my search go
i tried the builtin USB HOST in ESP32-S3 and it did not recognize the wheel,
i tried ESP32_HOST_HID and it initiated the wheel and managed to read values but could not configure it ,(and it did not recognize it just started it )
